# How to sort and what is the time complexity to sort a 2D array on 2 columns?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I want to sort a 2D array of 2 columns, first on column 0 then on column 1. Example :

```
1 2
3 4
1 5
2 6
```

After sort looks like

```
1 2
1 5
2 6
3 4
```

I know a simple sorting algorithm can sort based on 1 column, but when using column 0 first and then column 1, what should be the approach ? Also I am more interested in the time complexity of this. Will it be O(nlogn) only ? Or O((nlogn)^2) this is when all values in column 0 are same but sorting still takes O(nlogn) time, then sorting on second column again takes O(nlogn) time. Or am I taking it wrong ?

Sorting algorithm : Merge Sort

Comment: There isn't one sorting standard; many sort algorithms are available. Specify which one are you talking about here

Comment: Merge Sort @AbhinavMathur

Answer (score 2):

Merge Sort has 2 main steps:

1. Recursively sorting sublists of half length
2. Merging the recursively sorted sublists

Now, the process is same for both 1D and 2D arrays, the only thing that changes is the comparison of array objects. Here is a simple implementation of sorting key when integers are sorted:

```
def max(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return -1
    return 1
```

Now, considering a sorting key for pair of ints:

```
def max(a,b):
    if a[0]>b[0]:
        return -1
    if a[0]<b[0]:
        return 1
    if a[1]>b[1]:
        return -1
    return 1
```

Here, instead of just 1 comparison, we make 3 in the worst case. Thus, each operation might take 3x more time in the worst case. The overall complexity would still remain `O(c*nlog(n))`, where `c` is a constant. This boils down to the simple `O(nlog(n))` complexity.